# Delphi : Timage: Wait for an image to be displayed

Tags: delphi

There's a component on a form in my program.

The program must test:

if the loaded image is displayed on the screen. The size of this image can sometimes exceeded easily 2 mo.

To test if the image is loaded:

```
if Not (Image1.Picture.Graphic.Empty) then
```

...
But when it comes to an image that is large, it takes several seconds for it to appear.

I want to wait for the display of the image then make treatments on this image.

How to wait for the image to be displayed on the screen please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is your problem, does your program not wait for the image to load and continue? Are you somehow loading the images asynchronously? What is a "mo", mega octets?

Comment: my program does not wait for the image to load and process on this image.
if the image has a size of 40 méga octets, it will take a few seconds for it to appear on the acran. But that's not my problem.
My problem is: how do I know if this image is already displayed on the acran?                                                                                                                                                    Loading the image:             
`if Form1.OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin      
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile (OpenDialog1.FileName);
end;`         
  "mo" = méga octets

Comment: I would assume by the time the line after LoadFromFile executes, the image should have been loaded. Verify by putting a breakpoint on the line that follows "LoadFromFile".

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.  
I think you did not understand me.  
I give you an example:       
1-An image of 5 MB can take 1 second to be displayed on screen.     
2-A picture of 40 MB may take 5 seconds to be displayed on screen.  
So the display time of each image is irregular.            
is there a trick to know if the image is displayed on screen, that is to say that the user sees the image on its screen.

Comment: @Amélie the user will see when the image gets displayed, no?

Comment: Perhaps you need a "Repaint" on the image. Anyway, I understood what you are saying. It doesn't matter if it takes 1 sec or a minute to load the image, your code won't execute until then.

Comment: @ John Easley  : yes

Comment: The control works synchronously. When the call to LoadFromFile returns, the image will be visible after the next paint cycle. Use Repaint if you wish but better would be to respond to OnIdle.

Comment: I tested with Repaint, but that did not give me what I want

Comment: @ David Heffernan : I load the image into a Timage. after this loading, the application does a processing on this image just after this loading.

Comment: If you want help you have to be open. You wait until now to tell us that you have extra code that processes the image. Show a [mcve].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write an eventhandler for TImage.OnProgress

```
TProgressEvent = procedure (Sender: TObject; Stage: TProgressStage; PercentDone: Byte; RedrawNow: boolean; const R: TRect; const Msg: string) of object;
```

Check for Stage = psEnding

Comment: Thank you very much. it's what I am looking for.